# Executing commands consecutively based on log output

Tags: shell

I have a written a script to start my services one by one. After each service finish, it should execute the next command, and wait until first command executes for that I have given this command:

```
wait_for "Server started in RUNNING mode"
wait_for "socket listener started on port"
```

But it is not taking this logic

```
wait_for() {
    res=0
    while [[ ! $res -gt 0 ]]
    do
        res=$(tail -5 "$START_LOG" | fgrep -c "$1")
        sleep 5
    done
}
```

Comment: Instead of loop use `tail -f`

Comment: use `-l` flag for piped `grep`. It will quit on first match and `tail` will die too

Answer (score 0):

```
wait_for() {
    ( tail -n5 -F "$START_LOG" 2>/dev/null & ) | fgrep -l "$1" >/dev/null
}
```

`-F` means follow even if log rotated

`&` sends `tail` to background so parent shell doesn't wait for it to die. The process will hang there for a while until next message is logged.